# SublimeCodeIntel not working on PHP Sublime Text 3 Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, sublimetext3, sublimecodeintel

I've tried installing `SublimeCodeIntel` via `Package Manager` on my `Sublime Text 3` under `Ubuntu 15.10 as VM (VirtualBox)` but I cant get it to work.

Here is my SublimeCodeIntel.sublime-settings (User)

```
{
    "codeintel_language_settings": {
        "PHP": {
            "php": "/usr/bin/php",
            "codeintel_scan_extra_dir": [],
            "codeintel_scan_files_in_project": true,
            "codeintel_max_recursive_dir_depth": 25,
            "codeintel_scan_exclude_dir":[]
        }
    }
}
```

I can confirm that the php executable is on `/usr/bin/php`

Things that I've noticed while trying to make it work.

- the `~/.codeintel` folder is not being created after installing SublimeCodeIntel. (tried it many times - install/uninstall)
- `Info: processing PHP': Please wait...` is showing on status bar but nothing is happening after the text disappears. not even any popup autocompletion
- `CodeComplice` is also being installed sometimes (is it a dependency of SublimeCodeIntel?)

Answer (score 1):

Do `ctrl+shift+p` find the option

`SublimeCodeIntel: Enable Live Autocompletion for Current Language`